# Tried fixing the loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, project

I've been working on a game for my senior RAP project and I had this loop working up until recently. I need a way to iterate this when either player or enemy health equals 0. I **don't** want both of them to equal 0 which both of these examples do. I've tried rewriting this several ways and it wasn't working. Thanks for all who helped with this.

```
while (!(enemyHealth == 0 || playerHealth == 0)
{ //START WHILE
    Console.WriteLine("[System:] Here are the list of moves that you can do:\n1)Punch\n2)Kick\n3)Round House Kick");
    Console.WriteLine();
    decision = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    decisionNumber = int.Parse(decision);
    if (decisionNumber < 1 || decisionNumber > 3)
    { //STARTS IF
        throw new Exception();
    } //ENDS IF
    else
    { //STARTS ELSE
        enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attackNumber;
        playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyAttackNumber;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[System:] Enemy Health: " + enemyHealth + "\nYour Health: " + playerHealth);
     } //ENDS ELSE
} //ENDS WHILE



while (enemyHealth > 0 || playerHealth > 0)
                    { //START WHILE
                        Console.WriteLine("[System:] Here are the list of moves that you can do:\n1)Punch\n2)Kick\n3)Round House Kick");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        decision = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        decisionNumber = int.Parse(decision);
                        if (decisionNumber < 1 || decisionNumber > 3)
                        { //STARTS IF
                            throw new Exception();
                        } //ENDS IF
                        else
                        { //STARTS ELSE
                            enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attackNumber;
                            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyAttackNumber;
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("[System:] Enemy Health: " + enemyHealth + "\nYour Health: " + playerHealth);
                        } //ENDS ELSE
                    } //ENDS WHILE
```

Can anyone figure this out because I'm having major problems with it.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: What `problems` are you having with it? What does it do and what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @John Saunders I have. I've tried everything from breaking it down in parts to rewriting the loop. Nothing has worked. Theorectically is should work. I'm getting frustrated at it so I probably should've titled it something better than that but I couldn't think of anything with all the frustration. About threw my computer on the ground literally.

Comment: We can't tell you whats wrong with it because you haven't told us what its supposed to do, and what its actually doing. We all understand frustration, trust me. Just relax and try to expand your question

Comment: Patience young grasshopper, you will have many more occasions to throw your PC through the window. What exactly is the problem with the loop? It continue looping? It doesn't loop? What should it do?

Comment: Why would you want to continue to ask the player for their move only when either the enemy or the player is dead?  Your explanation doesn't really make sense...

Comment: It's suppose to leave the loop when the enemy's health or player's health hit's 0. It's then suppose to jump to the if statement below that which I don't have posted and tell whether they continue or end the program.

Comment: Continues looping when it shouldn't

Comment: Does your WriteLine ever show one of the health values as zero?

Comment: Maybe it's my poor *engrish* but, it seems to me you are doing the exact opposite in your code to what you say you are trying to do  :)

Comment: I think you may be a little confused on the logic of a `while` loop.  The condition in the `while` loop describes the logic for *staying* in the loop, not the condition for *leaving* the loop.  So when you say the loop should exit "when enemyHealth = 0 or playerHealth = 0", you need to **invert** this logic to create your condition for the `while` loop.  According to [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you would invert `(enemyHealth == 0 || playerHealth == 0)` into `(enemyHealth != 0 && playerHealth != 0)`.

Comment: .... if the logic of "exit the loop when this condition is true" makes more sense to you, then you can use `while(true)` to create an infinite loop, and break the loop at the beginning with logic like `if (enemyHealth == 0 || playerHealth == ) break;` to leave the `while` loop when the condition is true.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It does but it doesn't stop the loop until both are there

Comment: Is it ever the case that it prints both as zero?

Comment: Use a debugger....Really helpful!

Comment: I did but it wasn't giving me much information on it. @Ramhound It's already been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition could be simplified as, negative health level are `!= 0` that would create logic fault, also we need to keep the loop alive until health of `enemy` and `player` is `> 0`

```
while ((enemyHealth > 0 && playerHealth > 0))
```

---

Seems like , the problem is your coding withing the loop,

`throw new Exception();` seems to be a bad logic, my suggestion is discard ignore faulty input.

can be implemented like

```
while ((enemyHealth > 0 || playerHealth > 0))
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("[System:] Here are the list of moves that you can do:\n1)Punch\n2)Kick\n3)Round House Kick");
    Console.WriteLine();
    decision = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    decisionNumber = int.Parse(decision);
    if (decisionNumber >= 1 && decisionNumber <= 3)
    {

        enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attackNumber;
        playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyAttackNumber;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[System:] Enemy Health: " + enemyHealth + "\nYour Health: " + playerHealth);
    } 
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input : press enter to input again");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: And, FYI,  `(!(enemyHealth == 0) || !(playerHealth == 0))` is the same thing as `((enemyHealth == 0) && (playerHealth == 0))`

Comment: @radarbob - yes it is the same, but that is where the OP has done wrong with logic!

Comment: Downvoter - You are using || instead of &&. The fight will continue even if one of the fighters die. Is the living player going to continue to kick the crap out of the dead players body for eternity?

Comment: @Steve - thnx! ill fix that part!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you do this

`while (!(enemyHealth == 0) || !(playerHealth == 0))`

`enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attackNumber;`

`playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyAttackNumber;`

**If the enemy health is at.. lets say 20, and the attack number is 21, you get -1. It will never hit 0. You need to check if their health is greater than 0.**

`while (enemyHealth > 0 && playerHealth > 0)`

Use && because if either one dies, you want the fight to end.

Comment: Doesn't && stand for "and" while || stands for "or"

Answer (score 1):

why not just do

```
bool loop = true;
while(loop)
{
//change loop to false when it loop should stop
}
```

or use the `break` keyword

Comment: You don't need the bool. You could simply do while(true) { ... if(something) { break; } }

Comment: i was offering two different ways :)

Answer (score 1):

I would change the condition to this:

```
while (enemyHealth > 0 && playerHealth > 0)
```

This will stop the loop if the enemy or the player health drops to zero or less. It is safer to use greater than or less than comparisons instead of exact zero comparisons to prevent an infinite loop in the case that the health drops below zero (negative).

Answer (score 1):

Your language is a little confusing.  When you say

> I need a way to reiterate this when either player or enemy health
>   equals 0.

I think you mean you want to "**stop** reiterating" (i.e., leave the loop) when either player or enemy health equals 0.  To accomplish this, you need `&&` instead of `||`:

```
while (!(enemyHealth == 0) && !(playerHealth == 0))
```

This means continue running the loop as long as both enemy *and* player has non-zero health.  However, if it's possible for health to go negative (and skip `0`), this isn't good enough. You want to use:

```
while (enemyHealth > 0 && playerHealth > 0)
```

Comment: Doesn't && stand for "and" in programming?

Comment: @DustinKoeller it does in C#

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The problem is this is a `while` loop, not a `stop when` loop.  So you are describing the condition for *staying* in the loop, not the condition for *leaving* the loop.  So the logic will be inverted.  What you want is "leave loop when `enemyHealth == 0 || playerHealth == 0`", which translates to "stay in the loop while `enemyHealth != 0 && playerHealth != 0`". (See [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to understand what I mean)